# mongodb date query don't work with ISODate?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can find an item with this search:

```
db.item.find({"startdate":{$gte: 1485521569000 }})
```

The date seems to correspond to

```
> new Date(1485521569000)
  ISODate("2017-01-27T12:52:49Z")
```

But if I search

```
db.item.find({"startdate":{"$gte" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z")}})
```

I don't get any results. What am I doing wrong?

PS
the only way I found is

```
 db.item.find({"startdate":{"$gte" : (new Date("2017-01-01")).getTime()}})
```

is that right or there is a better way?

Comment: Please post a sample document from your `item` collection showing the field `startdate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below one will work.

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
  "key": {
    "$gte": (ISODate("2017-01-01")).getTime()
  }
})
```

Reason:

You have your data is in `int64` or `long`

In the `new Date` query, you are converting date to time which return `int`. So `get` performs `integer` comparison.

In `ISODate` you are passing a date, it doesn't convert date to `integer` i.e milliseconds. So if you convert, both will work.

> new Date() returns the current date as a Date object. The mongo shell wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper

```
var d = ISODate("2017-01-01")
print(d); //Sun Jan 01 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Hence, the comparison fails.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, you have timestamp in `startdate` field,

This is the option if helps you, Can do it with [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html) function, using [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/),

- `$toDate` convert timestamp to ISO date

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          {
            $toDate: "$startdate"
          },
          ISODate("2017-01-27T12:52:49.000Z")
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/H7SFHsgOcCu

Comment: Perfect approach of handling it.

Comment: @Gibbs hmm, BTW your answer's explanation very good when use `find()`.